# WCSession sendMessageData not working in watchOS 3

Tags: ios, swift3, watchos-3, wcsession

I am trying to send image from iOS to watchOS and I am getting below error.

> sendMessageData getting error: Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7014
>      "Payload could not be delivered."
>      UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Payload could not be delivered.

My code in ViewController Class

```
var session: WCSession?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        session?.delegate = self
        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            session = WCSession.default()
            session?.delegate = self
            session?.activate()
        }

    }

     let image = UIImage(named: "img1")!
     let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
     session?.sendMessageData(data!, replyHandler: { (data) in
          print(data)
        }) { (error) in
            print(error)}
}
```

In InterfaceController Class

```
  override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()
        if (WCSession.isSupported()) {
            session = WCSession.default()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }
    }

 func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessageData messageData: Data) {
        guard let image = UIImage(data: messageData) else {
            return
        }
        print(image)
 }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try below protocol as mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsessiondelegate/1615653-session).

```
 func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessageData messageData: Data, replyHandler: @escaping (Data) -> Void) {

    guard let image = UIImage(data: messageData) else {
        return
    }

    print(image)
    imageSet.setImage(image)
}
```